# Where are properties (like access token) of an authorized connector inside logic app workflow actually stored?

Tags: azure, authorization, connector, azure-logic-apps

Let's say I have Instagram connector inside my Logic App workflow, authenticated and authorized to perform actions on my behalf.
I can see this connection stored in  "$connections": sections but there is no access token or anything that really makes this connection work with instagram API.
The problem here is that available Logic App actions for Instagram are way from complete and for some API calls I have to use plain HTTP action and inject my access token manually.
My question - where is in general this information is stored by Logic App (OAuth tokens and so on) and how to access it inside workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available. I see what you want to do - if Instagram introduced a new API Logic Apps doesn't support, it would be cool to use a generic HTTP action, but use the token Logic Apps already retrieved for auth.

This is not possible because, it would be a violation of the terms of use for third party services to make token available so end users can make any arbitrary call, since it may be abused. And this would risk all Logic Apps user lossing the ability to communicate with said service when our API key is  revoked.

Comment: The last part doesn't make any sense on my opinion, sorry: 1) I use generic HTTP action anyway, I just need to go through authorization process manually and save received token inside workflow to use in generic HTTP actions. 2) Abuse of API use is controlled by Instragram. They can just revoke my apps' permissions to access it if they don't like it and Logic Apps has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @amarax when you use out-of-box connectors, you use our app id to connect to the 3rd party service, not yours.

Comment: Yes, I see now - I have "Azure AppService Logic Apps" in the list of Authorized apps in Instagram - you went through review process and and got "basic" scope permissions. 
So it anyway isn't going to work out of this scope. And yes, now I understand why I can't access this token - it isn't just mine but also bound to your instagram application Id that you don't want to risk.
What about after October 1st?